# Cloning .json files on python app

Tags: deployment, json, heroku, github

I have an issue of Heroku only cloning .py files but skipping .lock and .json ones. The files are necessary for my python script. Is there any reason why deploying from GitHub would cause it?

Update, not even my .py files were cloned. checked via:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
            for filename in files:
                print(filename)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cloned"? Are you expecting your application's source code files to be available in the web application's current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue on Heroku, due to the new dyno crashing.